# I miss my ylabel in my latex pdf file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I draw the pic with tex, and I have included all the packages listed:

```
  \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{paralist}
 \usepackage{uestc/common}
 \usepackage{uestc/tocfix}
 \usepackage{uestc/ftcenv}
  \usepackage{uestc/extra}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{bbding}
  \usepackage{subfigure}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{xeCJK}  
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{helvet}
  \usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
  \usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzset{font=\footnotesize}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   \pgfplotsset{
     tick label style = {font=\footnotesize\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\footnotesize\small\sffamily},
   legend style = {font=\footnotesize\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\footnotesize\sansmath\sffamily}}
  \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gincltex}
 \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
 \interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
  \usepackage{algorithmic}
```

and I draw the pics like this:

```
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
   \subfigure[Time of A.]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ch/06/figures/timeA.tex}
     \label{fig:bolas-response-time}
     }%
     \subfigure[Time of B.]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ch/06/figures/timeB.tex}
     \label{fig:bolasplus-response-time}
    }
   \caption{ Time comparsion.}
   \label{fig:response-time}
   \end{figure}
```

the two tex file written like this:

```
  \pgfplotstableread{
 0  105.0   81.3    65.3 
 1  146.3   131.0   113.7
 2  203.0   175.0   143.3
 3  226.0   183.7   192.7
 4  313.3   245.7   224.7
 }\dataset
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfplotsset{
   /pgfplots/sybar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=10pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
       plot coordinates {(0cm,0.5em)};},
    },
   }
    \begin{axis}[
         width=7.5cm,
         height=4.64cm,
          ymin=0,
         % ymax=320,
         ylabel={Time (s)},
          xlabel={数据块},
         xtick=data,
           xticklabels = {
             20,
             40,
             60,
             80,
             100
         },
         major x tick style = {opacity=0},
         minor x tick num = 0,
          minor tick length=0ex,
          every node near coord/.append style={
                 anchor=west,
                 rotate=90
         },
         ybar,
         bar width=7pt,
         sybar legend,
          legend entries={native, \bolasplus, \bolas},
         legend columns=1,
         legend pos=north west,
         legend style={draw=none,nodes={inner sep=2pt},nodes=right,fill=none},
         ]
 \addplot[draw=black,fill=green!40] table[x index=0,y index=1] \dataset; %
 \addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!40] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset; %
 \addplot[draw=black,fill=red!40] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset; %
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

but the ylabel not show in the final pic, may some geek in tex can help me, more than thanks.

Comment: Welcome, can you make your code snippets into  a small compilable document for us? For example, there are packages like `uestc/extra` which quite likely are unrelated. That would help the helpers in answering.

Comment: does it work at all to input a tex file with `\includegraphics` ?  I would have expected to see `\input` here: `\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ch/06/figures/timeA.tex}`

Comment: I also recommend to produce a __real__ minimal working example. Please add things like `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` to produce a TeXable document. Then remove all commands and `\usepackage`s that are not relevant to produce the error. Then edit your question and post this code and the chance is _very very_ high that we (the community) will be able to help you ...

Comment: ... also I want to note that from the code I would expect a "bar" plot, but the picture you are showing a "line" plot. Also you just provide code for 1 picture, but have two "figures" in the figure environment.